# Clicking on a video in my Photos library may crash the Photos app or does nothing

Tags: release-loki, photos

Photos either crashes or does nothing when I click on a video.

- What is the expected behavior?
- Should some sort of thumbnail of the video be shown, like I would see in Files? (Just also curious about this..)

Comment: What's the file format?

Comment: .mov files. I just found out that if I have the info pane open, select the video (checkmark style), then click it, it opens as I'd expect. So, good, kind of. But if I right click, crash.

Comment: Ah, be sure to report the bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/audience/+bug/ with the steps you took and the result so someone can fix it!